# Twilio API "IncomingPhoneNumber.list()" is slow on Master account (And I only need the total amount of numbers)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a Flask App that uses twilio. I display the total amount of incomingphonenumbers in an account/subaccount to the user.

Here is what I'm currently doing to get the total:

```
client = Client(accountsid,accounttoken)

# Get the list
pnlist = client.incoming_phone_numbers.list(limit=1)

# Get the length of the list
total = len(pnlist)
```

This takes upwards of 19 seconds just to get the numbers in the Master account. On top of that I have to repeat this for all subaccounts.

Is there a better way to just get the total numbers for a account/subaccount?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would recommend that, rather than listing all the numbers every time you want to count them, you cache the count within your own database against the account.

You can then update the count either when you know it changes, if you are purchasing/releasing numbers via the API in your app, or periodically (say, once a day) with a background job.

Comment: Got it. I will start keeping track of records internally as well then thanks.

Comment: While I have you, do you know of an API bulk number purchase option? That's been another pain point as we scale up. Thanks

Comment: There is not a bulk number purchasing API, I'm afraid. As for most API operations with Twilio, you make an API request for each action you want to perform. If this is going to grow a lot, then I would recommend investing in building background job processing into your application, so that you can queue up your bulk operations and perform them in the background.